# What is the Trick Behind SoCs. .?

Tags: lumia

I wonder what makes the difference between Lumia 630 & Lumia 535, for instance, Which possess SDragon S4 & S2 AND 512MB/1GB RAM respectively.
What is the trick behind using a low level chip combined with Higher RAM ratio. .?
Any technical aspects behind it. .?
Clear black is hardware related things,isn't they. .?

Comment: Is there a question there?

Comment: By trick do you mean idea, why they would use a slower processor with more ram?

Comment: Yes,Idea. .!! I meant for any Tech related Idea/Reason for doing so. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day, it all comes down to how much a phone may cost. If I had to close between a better processor or more ram, I'd go with the ram ad windows phone runs fine on low end hardware. However there are some apps you can't even install if you only have 512 MB ram. So better to have then run a bit slower than not at all.

And I imagine that's what Microsoft / Nokia thought as well.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is hidden behind the power of windows platform. Unlike android it is not heavy. So windows does not lag even with the small ram size. Now of things can go with sufficient amount of ram why would they use large amount of ram. Pretty simple.
And btw you could have searched in on the google.